# Custom date format (instead of %date) for WebForm e-mail title?

Tags: 7, webforms, datetime

I have an webform with e-mails adresses that I want to send notifications to.

I want to make the title of the e-mail as e.g. "new message 2017-03-20".

I have tried with pattern suggested under another field (e-mail body):

```
new message %date
```

But it output the formatted date:

```
new message sunday, march 25, 2017 - 17:54
```

Is there a way to put here date in `yyyy-mm-dd` format without chaning the global date formatting on the website?

I also tried to add something like the pattern that is not listed under field:

```
new message [entity-fetched:field_event_date]
```

but it does not get replaced at all (I get message with that literal title):

```
new message [entity-fetched:field_event_date]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place this code in a custom module:

```
     /* first add a custom date field (mydate), you have to set it's value with rules */
  /* change all capital letters with proper names (in lower case) */
  function YOURMODULE_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
$vars['MYDATE'] = 
t('!datetime', 
  array('!datetime' => format_date($vars['node']->MYDATE, 
    'custom', 'M/d/Y, h:i a')));
}
  /* hide custom field to all users but admin */
function YOURMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  global $user;
  $uuid = $user->uid;
  /*  check that user is NOT admin (No1) */
    if ($uuid !='1') {
        /* if is user profile form use: if ($form_id == 'user_profile_form')*/
      if ($form_id == 'YOUR_FORM_ID') {
      //dsm($form);
        hide($form['field_MYDATE']);
       }
 }
```

for a diferent format look at: http://php.net/manual/es/function.date.php

having date format correct, go agian and do:

```
new message %mydate
```

Comment: Thank you. One question: wouldn't it affect date format everywhere? I just want to set my custom format in message title (as is kind of serial number there) and not to change the format in mail body (if date is placed there too). Can it be distinguished inside `HOOK_preprocess_webform` somehow?

Comment: HOOK_preprocess_webform only affects webform, if you do HOOK_preproccess_node it will affect all nodes, HOOK_preproccess_page will affect all pages, etc. you may have to try several functions like HOOK_preprocces_webform listed on second link to see wich one does what you want,

Comment: That's not what I meant, let me expain my comment in another way. I want to affect date format in webform mail title and do not change date format in webform mail body (which may also use `%date`). Is it possible inside `HOOK_preprocess_webform` (I guess it will be called both for webform e-mail title and body)?

Comment: you may need another date field, a hidden one, set same value with rules,  format your custom field to fit you needs, original date field live it as it is. With this solution now you may use hook_preproccess_node on custom field and nothing will be changed, achiveing what you need.

Comment: can you make that last comment the alternative version of solution (adding it to aswer)? I feel like it may helps someone in future. I already marked your answer :)

Comment: done, i added a function to hide custom date field to all users but admin, sorry for indentation, i could not make look nice, thanks for flagging my answer.

Comment: i don't know why but i had to use code in this site, hope help others: if ($form_id == 'user_profile_form' OR $form_id == 'user_register_form')