# Create a custom date format

Tags: 8, datetime

Our organization's style guide expects dates in this format:

> Oct. 31 2018 01:30 p.m.

I looked the date format drop-down in our views, and there were several options, including a custom one. However, I noticed that none of these are able render the post meridien with abbreviating periods.

There is option for a custom date format, but it seems to use the encoding for PHP `date()` function. Looking at [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), there is `a`, which gives me `pm`, and `A`, which gives me `PM`, but I don't see anything specifying one with periods.

I looked in the code base for where date formatters are stored, and they all seem to be yaml files specifying `date()` formats:

```
$ cat core/modules/system/config/install/core.date_format.html_yearless_date.yml
...
pattern: m-d
...
```

So it seems that the built-in custom date formats are limited to what can be specified with PHP's `date()` function.

I googled for ways to create a custom date format, but only found explanations of where to specify a custom date format: https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/d8-dates/

How can I create a date formatter where I can use PHP code to give myself a date format with properly abbreviated meridiens?

Comment: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/232371/custom-date-format-instead-of-date-for-webform-e-mail-title/233015#233015

Comment: You are correct; the `date.formatter` service uses the native PHP date formatting when using custom formats.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, the core [`date.formatter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Datetime%21DateFormatter.php/function/DateFormatter%3A%3Aformat/8.6.x) service uses the native PHP [date formatting strings](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), none of which have 'a.m.' or 'p.m.' in them.

If you really need this, I suspect this would work.

- Create a new module, with a class that extends [`DateFormatter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Datetime%21DateFormatter.php/function/DateFormatter%3A%3Aformat/8.6.x).
- In the `format` method, call the parent method, and then do string replacment to convert 'am' to 'a.m.' and 'pm' to 'p.m.'
- [Replace](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/services-and-dependency-injection/altering-existing-services-providing-dynamic-services) the `date.formatter` service with the one you created.

This may have side effects that I'm not thinking of right now.

Comment: I think I will just do a js to update the format, but thanks : )

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new dateFormat like `Oct. 31 2018 01:30 p.m` here is the steps :

1. From `admin/config/regional/date-time/formats/add`
   Create new Format with `M d Y h:i A` as Format string.
   [image]
2. Create field of type date:
   [image]
3. `Manage Display` and `Manage Form display` for the field like the following:
   [image]
4. In the front you will get:

[image]

**Note**:
If you want to add period after month and `pm` or `am` Change `M d Y h:i A` by `M. d Y h:i a.`

Comment: This doesn't handle the need for "a.m." and "p.m." with the period in the middle, https://3v4l.org/JYkPR

Comment: Hello, thanks for responding. However, I am looking to get a fully abbreviated "a.m." and "p.m.".